# how to run multiple requests sequentially for each user

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to run http samplers sequentially for multiple requests. Where the output of 1 API response is the input of next API request. My concern is when I run with 5 users (for. e.g), then at given point of time it first executes 1st API with 5 users then second API with 5 users, in this process the API where input is required gets lost. Please help me on this. I need a solution, where all the samplers are first executed for first user, then for second thread all the samplers are executed and so on.

Comment: did you get the solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need to amend anything as JMeter is kicking off threads (virtual users) within the time frame specified in "Ramp-Up Period" input of the [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group). If you have 2 requests under the thread group than 1st user will execute 1st request followed by the 2nd request, same does the 2nd user. When there are no requests to execute and loops to iterate - thread is being shut down.

So each JMeter thread (virtual user) executes samplers upside down (sequentially). If you don't want concurrency (not to start 2nd user till 1st one finishes) - just configure your Thread Group to have 1 thread and 5 iterations

[image: JMeter Thread Group single user]

This way you will have only 1 thread at a time. You can provide credentials for different users using i.e. [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dmitri but I really have to execute these requests for multiple users(threads) and when I am doing that, the requests are run randomly i.e. the request1 is run for n(letsay 10) times and then request2 is run some x times(letsay 5) due to which there are conflicts as request2 is dependent on request1. But request2 is unable to connect with the request1 and hence it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Use loop count in the Thread, in the first loop it will run with the first user and then in the second loop it will run with the second user(which can be configured in the CSV file) this process will work on other counts as well below us the link.
[image: Jmeter screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I had this same use case and got around it by putting the calls that need to be chained together inside a Critical Section Controller.